# C# get absolute path from `~` on Unix-like systems

Tags: c#, path

I'm building a C# app on Mac OS. It receives any path as an input and have to save a file by this path. The problem I faced is with paths relative to user directory, specified as `~`.

I'm using following code `using var s = File.Create(path);` and there are few possibilities `path` parameter could be:

1. provided relative path e.g. `filename.txt` or `../filename.txt` - it works and creates this file relative to current working directory.
2. provided absolute path e.g. `/Users/username/Desktop/filename.txt` - also works as expected
3. but providing path relative to user directory e.g. `~/Desktop/filename.txt` - does not work. In this case `File.Create` is trying to combine absolute path like in case 1. It takes `current working dir` and simply adds my path like this `/Users/username/project/~/Desktop/filename.txt`. Which does not exist.

I tried to get absolute path from `~/Desktop` with `Path.GetFullPath("~/Desktop/filename.txt")`. It results to the same `/Users/username/project/~/Desktop/filename.txt`. Same with `Path.GetRelativePath("/", "~/Desktop/filename.txt");`

`Path.GetRelativePath("./", "~/Desktop/filename.txt");` returns not changed result.

Then tried `Path.GetPathRoot("~/Desktop/filename.txt")`. It gives just an empty string.

So the question, how in C# on Unix like host convert relative path like this `~/Desktop` to absolute path like this `/Users/username/Desktop`?

Comment: Which version of .NET Core/.NET are you using?

Comment: I'm using .NET6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to determine if the path starts with `~/` and, if it does, replace it with the path of the home directory. Here is a method that can do that:

```
public static string GetPath(string path) => 
    (path.Length >= 2 && path.StartsWith("~/"))
    ? Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), path.Substring(2))
    : path;
```

Use it like this: `GetPath("~/Desktop/filename.txt")`. This will return `/Users/username/Desktop/filename.txt` (provided that your home directory is `/Users/username`).

Comment: yeah, this is working solution, thanks! just hoped there is a standard library way to do it)